# php - set function without default value and call function without input value

Tags: php

I have updated php version from 5.3 to 7.1. I checked my website and found a problem.

```
function getComment($comment_id){
    $comment_sql = "SELECT * FROM comment";

    if($comment_id){
         $comment_sql .= " WHERE id = '{$comment_id}'";
    }

    $comment = $db->query($comment_sql, true);
    $comment = is_array($comment)? $comment : array();

    return $comment;
}

echo getComment();
```

It works in PHP 5.3, but it cannot be called in php 7. I need to modify the function and set default value.

```
function getComment($comment_id = ""){
    $comment_sql = "SELECT * FROM comment";

    if($comment_id){
         $comment_sql .= " WHERE id = '{$comment_id}'";
    }

    $comment = $db->query($comment_sql, true);
    $comment = is_array($comment)? $comment : array();

    return $comment;
}

echo getComment();
```

Is it caused by PHP version or PHP setting?

Comment: in PHP < 7.1 this is a warning, after PHP 7.1 this is a fatal error,  [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ff92afdfe8dac86e25744f840dff5bc816967b4) - tip you can change version in the sandbox.  `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError` 7.1+   < `<b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 1 for a()` - for me personally I have always coded with strict standards, so no notices depreciated or warnings are acceptable to me.  `error_reporting(-1)`

Comment: sidenote: your need `SELECT * FROM comment WHERE 1=1` if your going to use AND like that

Comment: Woudn't `$comment_sql .= " AND id = '{$comment_id}'";` be this `$comment_sql .= " WHERE id = '{$comment_id}'";`  Then without it its `SELECT * FROM comment` with it is `SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id = '{$comment_id}'"` which happens to be vulnerable to SQLInjection...  But thats another comment .... in any case they are missing `WHERE` completely.

Comment: emmmmmm... my typing mistake, but it is not the focus of the problem. Thanks for your answer, ArtisticPhoenix, I will be more careful in the future.

Comment: `getComment($comment_id = "")`  I would use `null`  as you are changing types by using a string.  I would expect it to be an `int`.  In PHP because it's loosely typed this is a bit optional and less important then other languages.  But ....

Answer (score 0):

This is not caused by a configuration option. And I am almost certain that it is not cause by PHP 7 but I need others opinion on that.

The bottom like is that you should never use an uninitialized variable and count on the uninitialized value as part of your business logic. Provide a default value for $a.

Comment: It is caused to PHP 7.1+ before this it was just a warning, which was not fatal.  With display errors off, you wouldn't see the warning.  You can verify this in the sandbox I posted in the first comment.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I verified and confirm it.